# Print Manager.msc missing in Windows 2003 Server R2

Tags: windows-server-2003, printing, windows

There is an msc that I'd really like to use: [printmanager.msc](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753109%28WS.10%29.aspx). Specifically I want to be able to force certain OUs to use specific printers without having to push the entire directory.

Now I've inherited a Win2k3 domain with a pdc and two secondaries, all patched and current. Unfortunately the printmanager and some other tools weren't installed originally, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to install them now (If you tell me to do [this](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Managing-Printers-Windows-Server-2003-R2.html) I am going to mock you without mercy). Can't find a download link for a version that will work, and I can't figure out how to get the older version from the install disks to work either.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm beginning to think I'm going to have to wipe one of the secondaries, and do a clean install.

Edit: Since this has turned into a popular question, I'll add the answer: I had to upgrade everything to RC2 in order to install the msc. It was a problem due to my original disks being well below the patched level of my system, so I ended up making an upgraded install disk, and working from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Windows 2003 R2 system, you can install Print Management from the `Windows Components section` in `Add/Remove Programs`.

If the system is not R2, you'll have to install the R2 components first (from the second CD-ROM).

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work. I don't need the regular "print" stuff, I need the schmancy msc that allows you to integrate your print services better with the AD.

Comment: This is *quite* strange, that console should be installed when you add that component.

Comment: As for using the 2nd CD, that's the root of the problem. At this point in patching, it won't let me pull anything off the 2nd CD.

Comment: Yea, I haven't been able to find a damn thing about it online. I can see the fricking file on the 2nd disk... I've added and removed print services, I've added and removed the print server role...

Comment: Was the AD schema extended for R2? Are your domain controllers R2?

Comment: @massimo: No, I'm not 100% certain...They were *supposed* to be, but I've dug and I can't find any evidence that they were actually updated. That'd pretty much explain everything wouldn't it?

Comment: If you have the second CD-ROM, you can safely update any Windows 2003 SP2 server you have; just run the R2 installer. You can also update the AD schema using the ADPREP tool in that same CD-ROM. The upgrade is totally safe, R2 introduced new features to Windows Server 2003 but you have to manually install and use them, nothing is enabled automatically after you upgrade a server and/or the AD schema to R2.

Comment: @massimo: Alas, my servers are SP2, and my CDs are SP1. Try to run anything, and it tells me the patches are out of whack. I'll have to see if I can make or steal some RC2 SP2 disks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for?  (pmcmgmt.exe)

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9BFB44F5-232A-4FB5-BC14-45BFD81B7AC1&displaylang=en

Comment: Nope. 3 out of 4 of those throw the "Microsoft installer detects the wrong version of Windows" error, and the 4th (idmu.exe) one is some Unix integration I have no use for.

A better version of the tools is here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=86B71A4F-4122-44AF-BE79-3F101E533D95&displaylang=en That one still does nothing for me.

Comment: Is this server 2003 R2 x64?

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=8F7DF3A5-E738-44B4-91EB-4907511F87C6&displaylang=en

Comment: Are you *SURE* the system is R2?

Answer (score 0):

I think that was part of the [Admin Tools Pack SP1 or R2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778255%28WS.10%29.aspx) (it's been years, so forgive me if I'm wrong) (scroll to bottom of that linked page for the downloads).

Answer (score 0):

Copy the folder and its contents "PMCSnap" to:

C:\WINDOWS\PMCSnap

Register these dlls:

findnetprinters.dll
pmcsnap.dll
ppcsnap.dll
puiobj.dll

Edit the "PATH" to include the folder "C:\WINDOWS\PMCSnap"
All Done!
Now you can use printmanagement from Administrative Tools or from run command.

P.S. I upload the folder PMCSnap to rapidshare
https://rapidshare.com/files/126883871/PMCSnap.rar